# Ember: Ember Data results into components

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

On my route im requesting via ember-data some records. Lets say the model-type is 'item'.

```
model: function(){
    return this.get('store').find('item');
}
```

now ive got a component named *'my-foo'* which should use the records to do something with the data. Therefore Im calling the component like that:

```
{{my-foo myItems=model}}
```

in my routes template. In the components js part, Im trying to get the myItems-field and iterate over them.

```
this.get('myItems').forEach(...);
```

Unfortunalety its not clear for me if the model i want to overgive to the component is an collection from records or just a single record (since on some routes the model is the `result of store.find('item')` on other `store.find('item', 23424)`.

**How can I check what kind of data arrives in the component.**

(Also Im wondering what kind of object is it since im using ember-data. Is it a DS.recordarray or a promise or something else at this time?)

Answer (score 2):

I can see two solutions to the problem:

1. Making component aware of the form that model receives
2. Checking and/or adjusting data type in component (*in my opinion better default scenario*)

**As for making component aware** - you could go with 2 approaches. Either differentiate in a way how your component take arguments, so there could be:

- `{{my-foo myItems=model}}` - when you expect to receive multiple items
- `{{my-foo item=model}}` - when you expect to receive single one

And then work accordingly further on, or - the second approach - is to actually split component (while extracting shared part to a different structure) so you would have `my-foo` for single items and `my-foo-array` for multiple.

Advantage of this approach is that you don't deal with *what-if-multiple* logic, that might grow to something  unmanagable later on, yet usage of it is dependant on project requirements.

**As for checking and/or adjusting** - you already have data in, so could make assumption that your data is dirty and sanitize it using [computed property](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html). Below example, where single item is wrapped into an array.

```cs
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  sanitizedItems: Ember.computed('items', function() {
    var items = this.get('items');
    if(!Array.isArray(items)) {
      return [items];
    } else {
      return items;
    }
  })
});
```

Since you're using `Ember.Data`, depending on your setup, you might get a promise instead of object/array. In this case, you might want to resolve promise using `this.get('items').then(function(items) { ... })`  before doing sanitization, yet the idea behind is exactly the same.

You can check full example: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/exlee/d7daf48ac72a470eab6f), [Twiddle](http://ember-twiddle.com/d7daf48ac72a470eab6f)